# R , Spatial Polygon

Tags: r, mapping, spatial, data-analysis

I am trying to create a spatial polygon data frame from a set of latitude,longitude and a corresponding value count with it. Each row need to be a single polygon. I can also create a shapefile and then again read it but instead I need to do it by simply creating a spatial polygon dataframe

Here is an example of my data:

```
head(Mydata)

    NA. count... zipcode   Latitude Longitude
1     1        1       0  44.200797  24.50230
2     3       67  560001  12.976594  77.59927
3     4       28  560002  12.963521  77.58211
4     5       90  560003  13.001914  77.57134
5     6       26  560004  12.943751  77.57376
6     7       34  560005  12.997989  77.62265
```

I have to depict the count corresponding to each location on an interactive map.
I have been through many other posts but could not find a solution. I am new to R so please bear with me.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I am sorry but this is my first ques on stack overflow . I'll keep it in mind and edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: What is count? You have for each point a vount value. I thought you want polygon data frame. Are you sure that you do not want a point data frame?

Comment: I actually need to create an interactive choropleth or heat map in which when we hover over an area, count should be displayed. I got a solution which can create it using a spatial polygon data frame. In that it is reading a shape file and using leaflet for plotting. I cannot download a shapefile as I need to create a portal where user can enter different data and according to that automatically spatial polygon data frame is created and map is plotted.

Comment: Can you provide your data?

Comment: No I am sorry. I can't, but it is similar to the example given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
library(dismo)
v <- voronoi(Mydata[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")]
Mydata$id <- 1:nrow(Mydata)

v <- merge(v, Mydata, by='id')
spplot(v, 'count')
```

Comment: I need to create an interactive choropleth map which has a base of a location defined by zipcode in the data like the one at: http://openbangalore.org/maps/ 
but areas differentiated using colors based on their count.

Comment: This is of course not possible based on your data alone (and a different question). But it is simple to do to that: get a datasource with the zip boundaries and then do `z <- merge(zip, Mydata, by='zipcode)`